# How to apply JSON on Spring MVC 4.0 app by using JavaConfig?

Tags: spring-mvc

I want to use JSON (jackson library) with my existing app by using JavaConfig (Spring MVC 4.0)

I have my configuration :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({ "my.package.controller" })
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean(name = "viewResolver")
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

I want to apply JSON configuration but I don't find a solution.

I think I must extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter. And another detail, I use Spring Security.

Could you help me ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView or org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView

Comment: I don't understand how to implement it. I think I must replace InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() by ViewResolver contentNegotiatingViewResolver but after I don't understand how to add JsonView.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one:

```
  @Bean  
    public ViewResolver contentNegotiatingViewResolver(  
                    ContentNegotiationManager manager) {  

            List< ViewResolver > resolvers = new ArrayList< ViewResolver >();  

            InternalResourceViewResolver r1 = new InternalResourceViewResolver();  
            r1.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");  
            r1.setSuffix(".jsp");  
            r1.setViewClass(JstlView.class);  
            resolvers.add(r1);  

            JsonViewResolver r2 = new JsonViewResolver();  
            resolvers.add(r2);  

            ContentNegotiatingViewResolver resolver = new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();  
            resolver.setViewResolvers(resolvers);  
            resolver.setContentNegotiationManager(manager);  
     return resolver;  

    }
```

And to add Jackson support should use MappingJacksonJsonView  or MappingJackson2JsonView

```
 public class JsonViewResolver implements ViewResolver {  
        public View resolveViewName(String viewName, Locale locale) throws Exception {  
              MappingJacksonJsonView view = new MappingJacksonJsonView();  
              view.setPrettyPrint(true);  
              return view;  
        }  
}
```

In application.xml just to clarify my example have this config

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
      <property name="order" value="1" />
      <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
           <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
           <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
        </map>
      </property>
```

So probably need to add mediaTypes to the ContentNegotiatingViewResolver in the @Bean method.

Check [this](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-contentnegotiatingviewresolver-example/) for more about the ContentNegotiation

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried with source code found but I probably missed something. Great thanks

Comment: Link to the explanations is the most valuable thing :)

Comment: It's MappingJackson2JsonView, not MappingJacksonJsonView :)